# Is there a way to get a quick answer from Facebook support team?

Tags: facebook, security, account-management

It's been several weeks and several emails, still no answers.  I suspended my account because I suspected that it was hacked.  I've been trying to get it reactivated through Facebook reactivation procedure.  When I get to the step 2 "Send Security Code", the code never get sent.  I logged that problem as a Login problem, as a bug, as a security issue and i never heard anything from them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not recommend it but you can try hijacking someones's request and see if you can get someone to email you. Be clear and not demanding. Be honest as well, if it is necessary work wise for you to get your Facebook account working again tell them.

Example

```
abuse+dt17u8y@facebook.com
```

where `+[filter]` is used to filter each situation.

Comment: The other one I think is appeals but I do not have a filter for that right now you can just try appeals@facebook.com and cross your fingers

Comment: Thank you.   I will send an email to appeals@facebook.com.

Comment: It took 49 days before my problem got fixed.